# How to collapse a string based on alternate delimiter in r

Tags: r, string

```
a <- c("abc","efg","hij","klm","nop","qrs")
```

I want to collapse string based on alternate delimiter(,). ie.

```
  "abcefg" "hijklm" "nopqrs"
```

Comment: It's not clear what your expected output is.  You may need `paste(a, collapse=",")`  The description and title is confusing.

Comment: ya if i do paste(a,collapse=",") . i will get something like this "abc" "efg" "hij" "klm" "nop" "qrs" . while i want my result to be like this "abcefg" "hijklm" "nopqrs". i want to collapse based on alternative delimiter

Comment: Please update it on your post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `c(TRUE, FALSE)` to extract the alternating elements of 'a' and `paste` with the elements extracted based on `c(FALSE, TRUE)`.  By using `c(TRUE, FALSE)/c(FALSE, TRUE)`, this will extract the elements based on the recycling.

```
  paste0(a[c(TRUE, FALSE)], a[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
  #[1] "abcefg" "hijklm" "nopqrs"
```

Or

```
  sprintf('%s%s', a[c(TRUE, FALSE)], a[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
  #[1] "abcefg" "hijklm" "nopqrs"
```

A slightly more efficient process would be

```
  indx1 <- seq(1, length(a), 2)
  indx2 <- seq(2, length(a), 2)
  sprintf('%s%s', a[indx1], a[indx2])
  #[1] "abcefg" "hijklm" "nopqrs"
```